# Выбор НЕ или НИ в стихотворении Евтушенко

Tags: грамотная-речь, не-или-ни

В стихотворении Евгения Евтушенко "Дай бог!" есть строки:

> ...Ни жертвой быть, ни палачом,
>   ни барином, ни попрошайкой.

**Не** или **ни** в данном случае?

Answer (score 4):

Вопрос закономерен, потому что у Евтушенко как раз отрицание:

Дай Бог быть тертым калачом,

Не сожранным ничьею шайкой,

Ни жертвой быть, ни палачом,

Ни барином, ни попрошайкой

Очень хочется поменять на НЕ: Дай Бог быть не жертвой, не палачом и т.д. Иногда при перепечатании  так и делают, поэтому на некоторых сайтах возможно прочитать и с НЕ. Но У Евтушенко нет ошибки, он знает русский язык и применил следующий пункт употребления НЕ-НИ:

Повторяющаяся частица ни имеет значение соединительного союза, например: По этой дороге ни проехать, ни пройти; Ни день, ни месяц от него не было вестей; Ни тихо, ни громко течёт рассказ. В этих сочетаниях "ни" по значению равно сочетанию "и не", т. е. выступает в функции отрицания. Ср.: Ворóн ни жарят, ни варят (Крылов); Сам он ни богат, ни знатен, ни умён (Тургенев); Елисей был старичок ни богатый, ни бедный (Л. Толстой).

https://pravopisanie_i_stilistika.academic.ru/73/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B8

Так что здесь **ни = и не**

Answer (score 0):

**Дай бог быть тертым калачом, не сожранным ничьею шайкой, ни жертвой быть, ни палачом, ни барином, ни попрошайкой.**

**1) Усилительное значение частицы НИ в составе союза НИ...НИ**

Правильность написания (выбор частицы НИ) можно проверить по тексту, а объяснение такое.

Частица НИ в данном случае имеет **усилительное значение**: дай бог быть **НИкем:** ни жертвой, ни палачом, ни барином, ни попрошайкой.

**Это соединительный союз НИ...НИ,** в состав которого входит усилительная частица НИ.

2) **Нельзя сказать, что выбор НЕ/НИ в таких конструкциях очевиден.** Сравнить. Он был не жертвой, не палачом. Он сам затруднялся определить свое положение.
Здесь нет повторяющегося союза НИ...НИ, но есть **повторяющееся отрицание.**

**Поэтому задача эта имеет  смысловое, а не формальное решение:** увидели повторяющуюся частицу и сразу решили, что это союз НИ...НИ.

Важно различать варианты с повторяющимися частицами НЕ и НИ.

**3) Примеры с повторяющейся частицей НЕ:**

**Повторяющаяся частица НЕ** может относиться к однородным членам, в том числе при противопоставлении.

Я **не богат, не знатен,** да и по летам ему **не пара**.

Но Кочубей богат и горд **не долгогривыми конями, не златом**, данью крымских орд,  **не родовыми хуторами**.

**Не бродить, не мять** в кустах багряных лебеды и **не искать** следа...

Он **не богат, не беден**, а среднего достатка.

4) **Парный вариант:**

(1) У нас же на вечной мерзлоте обитают **ни много ни мало** 26, 7 млн. чел (союз НИ... НИ в устойчивом обороте).

(2) Десять лет ― это **не много и не мало** (повтор частицы НЕ).